# WPF equivalent of the AccesibleName property

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility

In WinForms applications it's possible to name controls for accessibility clients using the [`Control.AccessibleName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.accessiblename.aspx).

WPF controls are lacking this property, so I'm wondering how I can give an accessible name to controls in an WPF application.

---

I've read the documentations and I know it all changed with the `UIA` but I still can't find a way to change this property. As stated in the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712258.aspx), there are two required properties :

- Name
- Automation ID

I can find `Automation ID` but not the name. Where is it hidden ?

Comment: What is Accessible Name?

Comment: Your answer should be here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712258.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.accessiblename(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks it's more clear like this. I added more info

Answer (score 7):

[`AutomationProperties.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.name%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is the attached property you are looking for.

You can either specify it directly in XAML:

```
<object AutomationProperties.Name="name" .../>
```

Or using the getter/setters on AutomationProperties:

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
...
AutomationProperties.SetName(control, "name");
```

...or...

```
control.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "name");
```